# Laravel file type validation for unrecognised file types

Tags: php, laravel, mime

I'm trying to validate file types in Laravel like this:

```
'rules' => ['mimes:pdf,bdoc,asice,png,jpg']
```

Validation works correctly for `pdf`, `png` and `jpg` but does not work for `bdoc` or `asice` files (files with those extensions do not pass validation).

My guess is that it probably does not work for those file types because they are not included in the MIME types shown here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Am I correct in that assumption? If so, how can I validate these file types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a custom validation rules for that specific file types.

Check the documentations on creating a custom validation here. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

**Update: Added some sample codes.**

Validation Rule

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class AcceptableFileTypesRule implements Rule
{
    protected array $acceptableTypes = [];

    public function __construct(array $acceptableTypes = [])
    {
        $this->acceptableTypes = $acceptableTypes;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $value
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
    {
        return in_array($value->getClientOriginalExtension(), $this->acceptableTypes);
    }

    public function message(): string
    {
        // Change the validation error message here
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```php
[
   'rules' => ['required', new App\Rules\AcceptableFileTypesRule(['pdf,bdoc,asice,png,jpg'])]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

From the vendor code at `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule.php`, the interface `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule` is now deprecated.

```php
namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Validation;

/**
 * @deprecated see ValidationRule
 */
interface Rule
{
....
```

The interface `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule` is now recommended for creating custom validation rules. So, to modify @Luigel's answer, the up-to-date implementation that is tested in Laravel 10 is:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule as Rule;

class CustomFileRule implements Rule
{
    protected array $acceptableTypes = [];

    public function __construct(array $acceptableTypes = [])
    {
        $this->acceptableTypes = $acceptableTypes;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $value
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function validate($attribute, $value, Closure $fail) : void
    {
        if(!in_array($value->getClientOriginalExtension(), $this->acceptableTypes)) 
        {
            $fail('Invalid document type uploaded');
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that it uses the Closure feature of PHP introduced in PHP 5.3 to report error messages.

The instantiation of the class remains the same:

```php
[
   'rules' => ['required', new App\Rules\CustomFileRule(['pdf,bdoc,asice,png,jpg'])]
]
```

**NB:** Take care to set the encoding type of your form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` before testing this.